# i have an error while training BERT model

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model

I'm trying to train my model using GPUs.

When I execute it I get this error below:

```
File "main.py", line 95, in train loss.backward()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 198, in backward torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 100, in backward allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: transform: failed to synchronize: cudaErrorIllegalAddress: an illegal memory access was encountered
# Added identdation for better readability
```

This error occurs when i use single or multiple GPUs.

How can i deal with this issue? Thank you

Here is the code of the BERT model (no segment input, no pretraining)
c.f. When I use another model, this issue didn't occure.

```
"""code"""
import math
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class HateClassification(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = config

        self.bert = BERT(self.config)
        # classfier
        self.projection_cls = nn.Linear(self.config.d_hidn, self.config.n_output, bias=False)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
    
    def forward(self, inputs):
        inputs = torch.transpose(inputs,0,1)
        # (bs, n_enc_seq, d_hidn), (bs, d_hidn), [(bs, n_head, n_enc_seq, n_enc_seq)]
        outputs, outputs_cls, attn_probs = self.bert(inputs)
        # (bs, n_output)
        logits_cls = self.sigmoid(self.projection_cls(outputs_cls))
        # (bs, n_output), [(bs, n_head, n_enc_seq, n_enc_seq)]
        return logits_cls.squeeze()
""" bert """
class BERT(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = config

        self.encoder = Encoder(self.config)

        self.linear = nn.Linear(config.d_hidn, config.d_hidn)
        self.activation = torch.tanh
    
    def forward(self, inputs):
        # (bs, n_seq, d_hidn), [(bs, n_head, n_enc_seq, n_enc_seq)]
        outputs, self_attn_probs = self.encoder(inputs)
        # (bs, d_hidn)
        outputs_cls = outputs[:, 0].contiguous()
        outputs_cls = self.linear(outputs_cls)
        outputs_cls = self.activation(outputs_cls)
        # (bs, n_enc_seq, n_enc_vocab), (bs, d_hidn), [(bs, n_head, n_enc_seq, n_enc_seq)]
        return outputs, outputs_cls, self_attn_probs
    
    def save(self, epoch, loss, path):
        torch.save({
            "epoch": epoch,
            "loss": loss,
            "state_dict": self.state_dict()
        }, path)
    
    def load(self, path):
        save = torch.load(path)
        self.load_state_dict(save["state_dict"])
        return save["epoch"], save["loss"]
""" encoder """
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = config

        self.enc_emb = nn.Embedding(self.config.n_enc_vocab, self.config.d_hidn)
        self.pos_emb = nn.Embedding(self.config.n_enc_seq + 1, self.config.d_hidn)

        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([EncoderLayer(self.config) for _ in range(self.config.n_layer)])
    
    def forward(self, inputs):
        positions = torch.arange(inputs.size(1), device=inputs.device, dtype=inputs.dtype).expand(inputs.size(0), inputs.size(1)).contiguous() + 1
        pos_mask = inputs.eq(self.config.i_pad)
        positions.masked_fill_(pos_mask, 0)

        # (bs, n_enc_seq, d_hidn)
        outputs = self.enc_emb(inputs) + self.pos_emb(positions)

        # (bs, n_enc_seq, n_enc_seq)
        attn_mask = get_attn_pad_mask(inputs, inputs, self.config.i_pad)

        attn_probs = []
        for layer in self.layers:
            # (bs, n_enc_seq, d_hidn), (bs, n_head, n_enc_seq, n_enc_seq)
            outputs, attn_prob = layer(outputs, attn_mask)
            attn_probs.append(attn_prob)
        # (bs, n_enc_seq, d_hidn), [(bs, n_head, n_enc_seq, n_enc_seq)]
        return outputs, attn_probs
""" encoder layer """
class EncoderLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = config

        self.self_attn = MultiHeadAttention(self.config)
        self.layer_norm1 = nn.LayerNorm(self.config.d_hidn, eps=self.config.layer_norm_epsilon)
        self.pos_ffn = PoswiseFeedForwardNet(self.config)
        self.layer_norm2 = nn.LayerNorm(self.config.d_hidn, eps=self.config.layer_norm_epsilon)
    
    def forward(self, inputs, attn_mask):
        # (bs, n_enc_seq, d_hidn), (bs, n_head, n_enc_seq, n_enc_seq)
        att_outputs, attn_prob = self.self_attn(inputs, inputs, inputs, attn_mask)
        att_outputs = self.layer_norm1(inputs + att_outputs)
        # (bs, n_enc_seq, d_hidn)
        ffn_outputs = self.pos_ffn(att_outputs)
        ffn_outputs = self.layer_norm2(ffn_outputs + att_outputs)
        # (bs, n_enc_seq, d_hidn), (bs, n_head, n_enc_seq, n_enc_seq)
        return ffn_outputs, attn_prob

""" attention pad mask """
def get_attn_pad_mask(seq_q, seq_k, i_pad):
    batch_size, len_q = seq_q.size()
    batch_size, len_k = seq_k.size()
    pad_attn_mask = seq_k.data.eq(i_pad)
    pad_attn_mask= pad_attn_mask.unsqueeze(1).expand(batch_size, len_q, len_k)
    return pad_attn_mask
""" multi head attention """
class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = config

        self.W_Q = nn.Linear(self.config.d_hidn, self.config.n_head * self.config.d_head)
        self.W_K = nn.Linear(self.config.d_hidn, self.config.n_head * self.config.d_head)
        self.W_V = nn.Linear(self.config.d_hidn, self.config.n_head * self.config.d_head)
        self.scaled_dot_attn = ScaledDotProductAttention(self.config)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(self.config.n_head * self.config.d_head, self.config.d_hidn)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(config.dropout)
    
    def forward(self, Q, K, V, attn_mask):
        batch_size = Q.size(0)
        # (bs, n_head, n_q_seq, d_head)
        q_s = self.W_Q(Q).view(batch_size, -1, self.config.n_head, self.config.d_head).transpose(1,2)
        # (bs, n_head, n_k_seq, d_head)
        k_s = self.W_K(K).view(batch_size, -1, self.config.n_head, self.config.d_head).transpose(1,2)
        # (bs, n_head, n_v_seq, d_head)
        v_s = self.W_V(V).view(batch_size, -1, self.config.n_head, self.config.d_head).transpose(1,2)

        # (bs, n_head, n_q_seq, n_k_seq)
        attn_mask = attn_mask.unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, self.config.n_head, 1, 1)

        # (bs, n_head, n_q_seq, d_head), (bs, n_head, n_q_seq, n_k_seq)
        context, attn_prob = self.scaled_dot_attn(q_s, k_s, v_s, attn_mask)
        # (bs, n_head, n_q_seq, h_head * d_head)
        context = context.transpose(1, 2).contiguous().view(batch_size, -1, self.config.n_head * self.config.d_head)
        # (bs, n_head, n_q_seq, e_embd)
        output = self.linear(context)
        output = self.dropout(output)
        # (bs, n_q_seq, d_hidn), (bs, n_head, n_q_seq, n_k_seq)
        return output, attn_prob
""" feed forward """
class PoswiseFeedForwardNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = config

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=self.config.d_hidn, out_channels=self.config.d_ff, kernel_size=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=self.config.d_ff, out_channels=self.config.d_hidn, kernel_size=1)
        self.active = F.gelu
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(config.dropout)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        # (bs, d_ff, n_seq)
        output = self.conv1(inputs.transpose(1, 2))
        output = self.active(output)
        # (bs, n_seq, d_hidn)
        output = self.conv2(output).transpose(1, 2)
        output = self.dropout(output)
        # (bs, n_seq, d_hidn)
        return output
""" scale dot product attention """
class ScaledDotProductAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = config
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(config.dropout)
        self.scale = 1 / (self.config.d_head ** 0.5)
    
    def forward(self, Q, K, V, attn_mask):
        # (bs, n_head, n_q_seq, n_k_seq)
        scores = torch.matmul(Q, K.transpose(-1, -2))
        scores = scores.mul_(self.scale)
        scores.masked_fill_(attn_mask, -1e9)
        # (bs, n_head, n_q_seq, n_k_seq)
        attn_prob = nn.Softmax(dim=-1)(scores)
        attn_prob = self.dropout(attn_prob)
        # (bs, n_head, n_q_seq, d_v)
        context = torch.matmul(attn_prob, V)
        # (bs, n_head, n_q_seq, d_v), (bs, n_head, n_q_seq, n_v_seq)
        return context, attn_prob
```

Comment: This looks like a memory problem. Are you sure you have enough memory for everything you want to store? BERT is bigger than for example DistilBert.

Answer (score 0):

What is your `device.inputs` in the following code.

```
positions = torch.arange(inputs.size(1), device=inputs.device, dtype=inputs.dtype).expand(inputs.size(0), inputs.size(1)).contiguous() + 1
```

Can you set specific gpu and try:

```
torch.cuda.set_device(device_num)
torch.cuda.set_device(0)  #for gpu id '0'
```

And also I suggest you to run your code with the `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1` env variable. `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING` makes cuda report the error where it actually occurs.

```
CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1 python your_code.py
```

I suggest you to use the latest version of the [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#linux-anaconda), if you're not doing that already. Also ensure you're using one of the latest stable CUDA [tookit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).